# How to clone repository with Composer without --prefer-source? (using Symfony 2)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

Scenario: I am working with Symfony 2.2. In my list of required packages is also one of my github repositories, let's call it "TestLib".

I know that I can define the github url as additional repository in Symfony's composer.json to download "TestLib" via Composer from Github.

Problem: I cannot commit to "TestLib" repository as there is no local .git directory in the "TestLib" directory. I guess composer is fetching a zip from Github and not cloning it.

So my question is: is there a way to specifiy in Symfony's composer.json that Composer should clone TestLib?

Question 2: Maybe my workflow is wrong - so if you also have this scenario - how do you handle this?

Comment: Why are you excluding --prefer-source as a possible solution?

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question after a Google search for a problem I was having. My guess is that the author doesn't want to grab the source for everything, but just for TestLib as this is the problem I'm currently having. Wow, going to answer a question only to find out you were the one who asked it a month ago, that's some freaking stackInception

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding `@dev` to the package version clones the repository too.

```
{
  "require": {
    'package': '*@dev'
  }
}
```

Also is possible setup `source` as preference in the `composer.json`

```
{
 "config": {
     "preferred-install": "source"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

What I typically do if I notice that a vendor has an issue is `rm -rf vendor/foo/bar` to remove it and then I run `composer install --prefer-source` to get it back as a git repo.

Comment: but then you get every package as a source, we need a way to specify perfer-source on a single package added to the require section of composer.json

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add my github repo to packagist.org then I did this:

```
composer require malhal/createdby dev-master --prefer-source
```

This appears to add the require line to composer.json and also get it as a git repo, unfortunately this only works once so if you wouldn't be able to reuse the composer.json for a new install and would need to delete the require line and then remember to do this same command again. This command also downloads the git repo you don't have to do another composer update.