# How to "prefer source" for a few selected dependencies, and "prefer dist" for the rest?

Tags: php, composer-php

I would like to install all the dependencies that are maintained by me using the "prefer source" option, and all the other dependencies not maintained by me using "prefer dist".

Is that possible with Composer? I was thinking there might be something like this, but I couldn't find it:

```
"my/dependency":"v1.2.3@dist",
"other/dependency":"v4.5.6@source",
```

Any ideas?

Comment: answer is given at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324411/how-to-clone-repository-with-composer-without-prefer-source-using-symfony-2?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply not allow your own dependencies to have a distribution download link.

That excludes using Github, but will happily work with any pure Git repository. Composer explicitly checks if the repo url points to Github and then tries to download from the known sources instead of cloning the repo, which usually is way faster.

So you probably should reference your local Git repos instead of Github (which I assume you are doing right now).

There is however no way to decide per dependency which method to use.

Comment: I never mentioned Git or Github. Some public repositories will download a zip, and some others will download the entire source history. In the docs it says that by default it will download source for not stable dependencies, and dist for stable ones, which I don't want. I want source for mine, and dist for everything else. Are you sure there is no way to decide per dependency which method to use? If so, bummer.

Comment: If some repos download dist, then they have announced the download URL for their packages. Others have not, and there is no way to change that unless you know the download URL and manually add it to your local composer.json file - and maintain it for new versions. As mentioned, for some repositories like Github, there is known meta info about where to locate a download, but this is not the general case.

Answer (score 10):

There is now a [preferred-install feature](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install).  (I'm not sure if this was available at the time of the original question)

> Defaults to auto and can be any of source, dist or auto. This option allows you to set the install method Composer will prefer to use. Can optionally be a hash of patterns for more granular install preferences.

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "my-organization/stable-package": "dist",
            "my-organization/*": "source",
            "partner-organization/*": "auto",
            "*": "dist"
        }
    }
}
```

This lets you specify for each dependency the preferred install method.

See the [repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) section for available ways the dependencies can be hosted.

Comment: This is the answer in 2019! Yeyah!